# Can I create a socket file on Mac?

Tags: macos, mysql, sockets

I am missing `/tmp/mysql.sock`. It has signature `srwxrwxrwx`. Is it possible to create this file by hand?

Comment: Presumably you're missing the socket because `mysqld` either isn't running or isn't attempting to read from that socket. Creating it by hand isn't going to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a MySQL question. The `mysql.sock` file should be created when you start mysql using `mysql.server start`. Restarting your server should create the file properly. If it doesn't then there's a chance that the server isn't set up to listen over a socket.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago a friend of mine told me of an issue with a missing socket file.
He was using a custom configuration file /etc/my.conf that was somehow troubling mysql.
When he removed the my.conf file and restarted the mysql server the socket file appeared again.

After a little search with this keywords I found a [discussion on a blog post](http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/03/16/missing-mysqlsock-on-mac-os-x/), where some people reported almost exactly the same problems, maybe you can get some more ideas there. Some people however had the file, but in a different location.

However, if mysql does not create the socket file at all, it will not help you creating it by hand.